# JQuery Mobile + ASP.NET - Buttons Not Firing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, jquery-mobile

I have been searching through this site for an answer but I'm stuck.

Can someone please help me with the following question. I have a ASP.NET project written in VB and uses the jQuery Mobile 1.2.0 version.

I have a default page where there are 2 buttons (login / about), these work and redirect to the login page. However on the login page the login button event does not fire - it simply re-directs back to the default page. The same is true on the about page with a simple redirect button.

If I however refresh the login page then the buttons work?

Below is the code:

```asp
<%@ Page Title="Login" Language="vb" EnableEventValidation="false" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="login.aspx.vb" Inherits="Sequencing.login" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="page_title" runat="server">
Login
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="pageheader" runat="server">
<h1>Login</h1>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" runat="server">

<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" 
    data-transition="pop" runat="server" 
    Visible="False">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>

<div align=center class="ui-bar ui-bar-c">

<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/McD_logoimage.png" /><br />

<h3>Planning the Future</h3>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>

<asp:Login ID="Login1" DestinationPageUrl="~/user/Main.aspx" runat="server" Width="100%">
<LayoutTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" value placeholder="Username"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="cvUserName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="Login1" Display="Dynamic">    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" type="password" runat="server" value placeholder="Password"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="cvPassword" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password"     ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="Login1" Display="Dynamic">            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" Text="Remember me!" />
<asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
<asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" data-role="button" data-theme="b"     CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="Login1" onclick="LoginButton_Click" />
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
    </ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Further to this - I have looked up how to disable jQuery Mobile and have added the code to the site master where the jQuery is referenced - however still no joy!

```
<script>
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
        //apply overrides here
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    });
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript"     src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Anyone else got any ideas?

Comment: We can not help you with that code. Maybe only if you have it live. The jQuery mobile some times is move the page in a dynamic created div, and that is usually out side the form and that is the reason that is not fired.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean by that? I have published the site - and it doesn't work in live either.

Comment: Can you give us the url to test it ? and see whats going wrong.

Comment: ewww... UpdatePanels. Could be part of the problem

Comment: http://seq-dev.rs-mcd.co.uk/ - on the default page click the 'Login' button then you will see what happens when you click the login button on the login control - the event does not fire and it returns to the default page. If you refresh the page prior to clicking the login button it works ok?!

Comment: I have tried the code without the update panels aswell - it still doesn't work!

Comment: Do you fix it ? because as I test it, I see now that is working.

Comment: I see your problem, it is not working correctly for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you refresh the login page, you will see that the form looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="Login.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="form1" class="ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-c">
```

However, if you notice, when you first navigate to http://seq-dev.rs-mcd.co.uk/, then click "Login", the `<form>` element on the login page looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="form1" class="ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-c">
```

Notice that the form doesn't have the correct `action` or `onsubmit` values which are required for ASP .NET to work properly.

I don't have too much experience with jQuery Mobile, but I do see that it's doing its "AJAX navigation" magic, which is screwing with ASP .NET. Generally speaking, ASP .NET doesn't play nicely with jQuery mobile (or the other way around?). Maybe you can disable AJAX navigation somehow - that might do the trick. You're going to continue to run into this problem with server side events in ASP .NET if you can't disable the AJAX navigation.

Hopefully this points you in the right direction.

**EDIT**

After some searching, I found [this blog post](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2011/05/10-handy-jquery-mobile-tips-and-snippets-to-get-you-started/) which explains how to disable the jQuery Mobile AJAX Navigation. Here's the relevant snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    // disable ajax nav
    $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;
  });
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have disabled the script manager and the update panels and its still the same. Its still performing the same.

Comment: You misunderstand. ASP .NET is not causing the problem. Removing update panels and script managers won't help. You need to disable the AJAX navigation behavior of jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Ahh I see - have you got any idea how to do this?

Comment: Steve, please see the code I just put in the answer with my latest edit. Hopefully this helps you!

Comment: Thanks - I found this elsewhere but it didn't seem to make a difference... however it is now working, but not sure why?!

Answer (score 2):

Open the `jQuery-mobile.js` and search for "submit", the submit behavior is differently implemented in mobile version of `.js`.

So please comment that submit function in mobile `js`, then your asp.net forms will be submitted according to its behavior.

Commenting on that submit behavior in mobile `js`, you will not loose any features, so just comment it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the submit behavior to false and then add an OnClick event like below.

.aspx page -
asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" CssClass="Button" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click">

.aspx.vb page -

## Region "Button Click Submit"

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Response.Redirect("CanegateMidShiftTempB6TY.aspx")

End Sub
```

## End Region